# Custom Android OS Build

Tags: android

I was wondering what the feasibility would be for creating a custom Android build and deploying it on a currently available device on the market. Are there any documents or guidelines that describe the process?

Thank you in advance,
Sammy

Answer (score 2):

Try [dsixda's Android Kitchen](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246). While the kitchen is closed, the recipes are still posted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try my [blog](http://techshek4u.blogspot.in/2012/01/applying-card-emulation-patch-to_03.html) , this explains not even building but also flashing the build images(system,data and boot) after the build from the AOSP.I have tested it on Nexus S (code name - crespo)
Rgds,
Softy